# Frozen screen after error handler called

Tags: ios, uialertview

We process credit card transactions in our app. Whenever there is any transaction declined or any error we will go back to previous screen and we ask the customer to use another credit card.

PaymentController.m

```
    [sharedVtp processSaleRequest:saleRequest
                completionHandler:^(VTPSaleResponse* response)
     {
         [self saleRequestComplete:response];
     }
      errorHandler:^(NSError* error)
     {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Your transaction is declined" message:@"Please use another card and proceed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 });

     }];
```

The control goes back to the previous screen, but the screen is frozen. We cannot click on any buttons on that screen.

Comment: First of all, UIAlertView has been deprecated for years. Stop using it. Second, how can you show an alert _and then_ pop back while the alert is still showing? That makes no sense. Third, what you describe sounds _right_: while an alert is showing, the user cannot tap anything else; alerts are _modal_. So my only surprise is why you are surprised.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, [`UIAlertView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertview) is ***hella*** deprecated and you should be using [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller?language=objc). Also, as noted you cannot show an alert and then pop the view while the alert is showing.

Here is how you could fix it (replacing what is inside your main queue block):

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Your transaction is declined"
                           message:@"Please use another card and proceed"
                           preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"OK" style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler: ^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}]];

[self presentViewController: alert animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Note how the pop call is now only called in the action handler for the `UIAlertController`, which means it will only be called *after* the user has pressed the OK button.

Depending on what you want to do, you could also use a `UIAlertController` in a toast-like style, where you don't add any `UIAlertAction`s and instead you call dismiss on the alert controller a few seconds after it presents (in the completion block of the `presentViewController` call, using a dispatch after call).

Answer (score 0):

You are showing an alert. Alerts are modal; the user cannot tap anything else but the alert while the alert is present. So just show the alert and *stop*. The user must now interact with the alert. Don't try to do anything else until the user *dismisses* the alert. *Then* you can navigate elsewhere.

And stop using UIAlertView. You should be using UIAlertController.